# How do you download blockchain data (transactions etc.) using a node? Best ways to get a node?

Tags: nodes

I am just curious how one can download bitcoin data and blockchain using a node. Where should I start?

Answer (score 2):

> **I am just curious how one can download bitcoin data and blockchain using a node**

One way is to download and install a [full-node desktop wallet](https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet) such as Bitcoin-core.

When it is first started it will download the full blockchain. This may take a week - depending on your Internet-connection's bandwidth.

---

> **Where should I start?**

https://bitcoin.org/en/ is probably a reasonable place to start.

Ask questions here (one at a time) about any problems understanding or using Bitcoin. But use the search function here first - lots of great answers already exist for many problems.